# How to remove a new line for each integer?

Tags: c++, cin, endl

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    cin >> a >> b >> c;
}
```

When I compile it, every integer is asked like there is `endl` between them. How can I write that so the program asks for `a`, `b` and `c` in one line and space between?

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: your code can handle this, try input 3 space-separated integer yourself.

Comment: What you are asking for is exactly how `operator>>` already works. It reads whitespace-delimited values, and spaces and line breaks are both treated as whitespace. Otherwise, you can use `std::getline()` to read an entire line of input as a single `std::string`, and then use `std::istringstream` to read values from that string